# Increase size of images in view page

Tags: magento-1.8, product-images

In product view page page, images are serving from this path :

`media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/350x350/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/h/image-name.jpg`  :

but I want to serve from this path :

```
`media/cache/images/1/thumbnail/602f0fa2c1f0d1ba5e241f914e856ff9/catalog/product/c/image-name.jpg` :
```

**media.phtml**

```
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $dexxtz = Mage::helper('productzoom');

    $dexxtz->getCss();
    $dexxtz->getJs();
?>

<ul id="etalage">
    <li>                
        <img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')); ?>" />
        <img class="etalage_source_image" title="<?php echo $_product->getImageLabel(); ?>" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'), true); ?>" />
    </li>
    <?php 
        foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image) {
            if(Mage::registry('current_product')->getImage() != $_image->getFile()) { ?>                
            <li>
                <img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())); ?>" />
                <img class="etalage_source_image" title="<?php echo $_image->getLabel(); ?>" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()), true); ?>" />
            </li> 
        <?php 
            }    
        }
    ?>   
</ul>
```

or i want to display big size images in product page.

Comment: You want to display thumbnail images in big size ?

Comment: @SHPatel if you help me to serve images from this path, it will be really helpfull for me :

`media/cache/images/1/thumbnail/602f0fa2c1f0d1ba5e241f914e856ff9/catalog/product/c/image-name.jpg`

Comment: <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(135,135); ?>

Comment: @SHPatel Now its coming from this path : `media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/835x835/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/h/image-name.jpg`

Comment: Yes, Please add my above reference code it will give you thumbnail images from you have given path. Have you use my code and checked or not ?

Comment: @SHPatel yes, it gave thumbinal path, but it is not coming from path that i required , for some reason, i need to serve the images from path i mentioned in question.

Comment: given path by you it is current product image which you checked on detail page ?

Comment: @SHPatel in the path , images are there, please check  [link2](http://totaltoys.com/media/cache/images/1/thumbnail/602f0fa2c1f0d1ba5e241f914e856ff9/catalog/product/c/h197daf6fdf8885bc92bb6b117576f33d.jpg)

Comment: send me product Url which you are checked on detail page,

Comment: @SHPatel please check [here](http://test.collagekingapp.com/chhota-bheem-himalayan-adventure-bow-arrow-sword-set.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this locate the following file.

```
app\design\frontend\<package_name>\<theme_name>\template\catalog\product\view\media.phtml
```

near line no near 40-45 you will find a code of image like

```
<img id="image-main"
             class="gallery-image visible"
             src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image') ?>"
             alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()) ?>"
             title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()); ?>" />
```

Replace this code By

```
<img id="image-main"
             class="gallery-image visible"
             src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail'); ?>"
             alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()) ?>"
             title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()); ?>" />
```

That's it you will get a changed path for a image.

**Please not you will get a image here which you set as a Thumbnail image in admin for a product.**

Comment: we are using custom module to serve the images, i posted code of media.phtml in question. please update the answer with code for that media.phtml

Comment: can you please tell me which is you main image  i.e. for which image you want to change a path the one who is having  **etalage_source_image** as a class name second `<img>` tag of first `<li>` tag ?

Comment: i have to chnage this line of code : `<img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')); ?>" />`

Comment: replace that code with `<img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')); ?>"`.

Comment: now its serving from this path : `media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/350x350/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/h/image-name.jpg`

Comment: now its serving from this [path1](http://test.collagekingapp.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/835x835/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/h/chhota-bheem-himalayan-adventure-bow-arrow-_-sword-set.jpg)

but i want from this [path2](http://totaltoys.com/media/cache/images/1/thumbnail/602f0fa2c1f0d1ba5e241f914e856ff9/catalog/product/c/h197daf6fdf8885bc92bb6b117576f33d.jpg)

Comment: they are two different domains. you want your image to be served from other domain?

Comment: no no, sorry . you can just take refrence regarding image path, please ignore domain.

Comment: please check, i updated proper links : now its serving from this [path1](http://test.collagekingapp.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/835x835/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/h/chhota-bheem-himalayan-adventure-bow-arrow-_-sword-set.jpg)

but i want from this [path2](http://test.collagekingapp.com/media/cache/images/1/thumbnail/602f0fa2c1f0d1ba5e241f914e856ff9/catalog/product/c/h197daf6fdf8885bc92bb6b117576f33d.jpg)

Comment: as per my knowledge magento doesn't clear cache directory under media. how it is creating in you case? please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: we are using custom module. that is the problem.

Comment: in that case it is quite difficult to tell you the exact solution as for this we need to know the name of that module and need to study how they store images.

Comment: we are using this [module](https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/advanced-seo-suite.html) its generating this kind of url in google sitemap.
we need same image url in product image. our seo team suspects google is not indexing product images . so they are thinking if we keep same url in both places, they may index.
i am not in position to convince my seo team :-(

Comment: :) check are they storing path for `h197daf6fdf8885bc92bb6b117576f33d.jpg` in any of the table of DB.

Comment: let me check db and i will update you.